# Rewinding HTML 5 video each time the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make sure my HTML 5 videos start running from the beginning when the user enters a page.

At the moment, the first video is running fine, but if the user closes the pop-up while playing the video will start from where the user left it when they open the pop-up again.

Comment: sure.creating html for fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try siomething like

```
document.getElementById('vid').onload = function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
};
```

Comment: thnx but dude if the video is finish i want a button for reply...as in downloaded video there is no reply button just like youtube

Comment: @SACHIN yours very welcome ...you can use the onclick event for that